# Laravel Eloquent - Multiple Form Subquery

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and the Eloquent ORM that it provides but I'm struggling to select the data I need. I have 2 Models

```
Company
Member
```

How can I do that?

```
SELECT * FROM members m, companies c 
WHERE (m.main_type = "2" AND m.main_id = c.id AND m.status = "1") 
AND ((m.username LIKE "%keywords%") OR (c.name LIKE "%keywords%"))
```

Comment: Please show table structure for both table

Comment: Do you have a relationship between models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering company can have multiple members, you need to have relationship first like :

`Company` Model :

```
public function members(){
    return $this->hasMany(Member::class);
}
```

`Member` Model :

```
public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class,'main_id');
}
```

Then you can use relationships to get data :

```
$result = Company::with(['members' => function($q){
    return $q->where('main_type', 2)->where('status', 1)->where(function($sq){
        return $sq->where('username', 'like', '%keywords%')
                  ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%keywords%');
    });
}]);
```

A heads up that update relationships as per your foreign  key names. I wul suggest keeping more intuitive like `member_id` or `company_id`

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this. you don't need to the subquery.

```
Member::join('companies', 'companies.id', '=', 'members.main_id')
    ->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('main_type', 2)->where('status', 1);
    })->where(function($query) {
        $query->where('username', 'like', '%keywords%')->orWhere('name', 'like', '%keywords%');
    });
```